# Combinatorics; Distributing meat to children

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions

Let there be $4$ kids; people represented as $A, B, C,$ and $D,$ respectively. I'm distributing $6$ strips of bacon and $6$ pork slices to these kids. How many ways can I distribute these items if each kid gets **exactly** $3$ pieces of meat.

There are $6$ pieces of $2$ different types of meat each. I would think to just use $\displaystyle{\binom{12}{3}},$ since there are $12$ pieces of meat in total. There are four kids, so it would just be $4\cdot\displaystyle{\binom{12}{3}}=\boxed{880}.$

Is there something wrong with my strategy?

Comment: You can completely ignore one type of meat: you're distributing 6 items among 4 bins such that each bin gets at most 3 (and you fill the rest with the other type). Try and calculate that instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Or restate in another fashion? I'm not fully understanding what you're saying.

Comment: The problem is equivalent to the following: how many ways can you distribute 6 strips of bacon to kids A-D such that each kid gets up to 3 strips (and may get 0).

Comment: well, not exactly. There are $12$ different pieces of meat.

Comment: As in the posted answer, I mean "equivalent" as in "has the same numerical answer"

Comment: oh alright, then yes. Your interperatation would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be right if you had $12$ distinguishable items, and you wanted to count the ways to pick a child and $3$ of the $12$ items and give those $3$ items to the chosen child, but that’s a completely different problem. You don’t have $12$ distinguishable items: the bacon strips are indistiguishable, and so are the pork slices. And you aren’t just picking $3$ of them to give to one of the children.

Notice that if you know how many strips of bacon each child gets, you also know how many pork slices each child gets, because each child gets $3$ pieces altogether. Thus, we we’re really being asked to find out in how many ways $6$ strips of bacon can be distributed amongst $4$ children if each child is to get **at most** $3$ strips. This is a small enough problem that you can do it by brute force. It turns out that there are $5$ different kinds of distributions:

- one child receives $3$ strips of bacon and each of the other children receives one strip;
- one child receives $3$ strips, one receives $2$ strips, and one receives $1$ strip;
- two children receive $3$ strips each;
- three children receive $2$ strips each; and
- two children receive $2$ strips each, and the other two children receive $1$ strip each.

Try to count the distributions of each of these five types; then you can simply add those five numbers to get the answer to the original question. I’ll get you started with the third type in that list: there are $\binom42=6$ ways to choose two of the four children to receive $3$ strips each, so there are altogether $6$ distributions of this type.

Comment: The problem specifically states that each student must exactly have $3$ pieces of meat, though.

Comment: @StarLight: I know: that’s why it’s enough to consider how the bacon is distributed. Once we know that a child has $2$ strips of bacon, for instance, we automatically know that the child has $1$ pork slice. It’s precisely that condition that makes the problem easier.

Comment: Oh! That seems rather slick.

Comment: @StarLight: I’m lazy: I look for ways to make things simpler and easier. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the  third type is $\binom{4}{2}.$

Comment: @StarLight: At that point I’m considering only the distributions that give $3$ strips to each of two children, so that the other two children will receive no bacon (but of course will each get $3$ pork slices). Once I know which $2$ of the $4$ children are getting the bacon, I know what every child is getting, so there is one such distribution for each way of choosing the two kids who get the bacon. There are $\binom42$ ways to pick $2$ kids from a set of $4$ kids.

Comment: So for example, for the fourth case, it would be $\binom{4}{3}.$ 

How about cases like the first one, where the children receive different amounts?

Comment: @StarLight: Yes. Alternatively, you could notice that there are $4$ ways to pick the one child who does **not** get bacon. Either way you find that there are $4$ distributions of that type.

Comment: How about cases like the first one, where the children receive different amounts?

Comment: @StarLight: The first one is really just like the fourth; it’s the second one that requires a different idea.

Comment: How would we do the second one, then? Also, would the first one also just be 4 C 2?

Comment: No, in the first one everything is known once you know which child gets $3$ strips (or, equivalently, which $3$ children get $1$ strip each). That’s not $\binom42$, but rather … ? The second is just the multiplication principle. How many ways are there to choose a child to get $3$ strips? Once you’ve done that, how many ways are there to choose a child to get $2$ strips? And so on.

Comment: Oh number one would be 4 C 4

Comment: After computing all these values, would we just multiply them all together to get are final answer?

Comment: No, the first is just like the fourth: $3$ children get one amount, and one child gets a different amount. There are $4$ ways to choose the child who gets the different amount, which in this case is $3$ strips, so there are $4$ distributions of this type. Why would you multiply these five numbers? That would give you the number of ways of making a distribution of the first type with one set of four kids,  then a distribution of the second type with a set of four kids, and so on through the fifth type. Here you're simply counting the distributions of each possible type, and you want the ...

Comment: ... total number of distributions of all possible types, so you do what with the five numbers?

Comment: Add them all up.

Comment: @StarLight: Yep; and you should get $44$.

Comment: I did! Thanks you for walking me through all the cases and helping along the way. In the end, we get 44! :)

Comment: @StarLight: You're welcome.